# Find top level li with jQuery

Tags: jquery, parent

Let's say i have a menu like this...

```
<ul class="main_menu">
    <li class="item-1">
        First top level item
        <ul>
            <li class="item-2">Item 2</li>
            <li class="item-3">
                Item 3
                <ul>
                    <li class="item-4">Item 4</li>
                    <li class="item-5">Item 5</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-6">Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-7">
        Second top level item
        <ul>
            <li class="item-8">Item 8</li>
            <li class="item-9">Item 9</li>
            <li class="item-10">Item 10</li>
            <li class="item-11">Item 11</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

...and in this case the sub menus can be at variable depth, how can i get the top level item if i only know an sub item? For example, i know the class item-5, then i want to get the class "item-1", or if i know the "item-11", i want "item-7".

That is, wherever i am, i want the "Top level item X".

Comment: I think you might need to traverse up the DOM tree to `.main_menu`, and then take one step back to find the `<li>` you're looking for.

Comment: @floris but how would you know which top level `li` was the parent of the one which was clicked?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can chain [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) into [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
var topListItem = $(".item-5").parents("li").last();
```

This solution works because `parents()` returns the ancestor elements ordered from the closest to the outer ones.

If you want the original element to be part of the search (i.e. `.item-7` returning itself), then you can chain `parents()` into [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/), then into [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
var topListItem = $(".item-7").parents("li").addBack().first();  // '.item-7'
```

`addBack()` adds the original element back into the chain of parents. In this case, we have to apply `first()` instead of `last()` because `addBack()` puts the elements in document order (so the top-level element will be the first one matched instead of the last).

Comment: @Romaindr, why? My answer doesn't even contain an event handler.

Comment: This works really well! Looking at it, jQuery is freaking awesome, and this looks actually too easy. Thank you!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I was just guessing he wanted that piece of code on click of an li....

Comment: another question regading this then, what if the page i know IS the top level? that is, if i know "item-7", it should find itself. I guess i'll need a statement for this or something, or can it be done in this line?

Comment: @gubbfett, it is indeed possible, I will update my answer in a few moments.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parents()` and `last()`;

```
 // assuming 'this' is an `li` element:
 var $topLi = $(this).parents('li').last();
```

Note that jQuery traverses up the DOM, so the last element in the selector will be the top level parent.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick

```
$('.item-4').parents('li').last();
```

Comment: What if it is two levels down? This would return multiple li's.